# dplyr Use pivot_longer and pivot_wider on subset of variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to use `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` on a subset of a variable? Here's an example. First, I'll create a data frame with the desired starting structure.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Assume this as starting df
arrests <- USArrests %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "State") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-State, names_to = "Crime", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup()

arrests
# A tibble: 200 x 4
   State   Crime    Value Total
   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Alabama Murder    13.2  328.
 2 Alabama Assault  236    328.
 3 Alabama UrbanPop  58    328.
 4 Alabama Rape      21.2  328.
 5 Alaska  Murder    10    366.
 6 Alaska  Assault  263    366.
 7 Alaska  UrbanPop  48    366.
 8 Alaska  Rape      44.5  366.
 9 Arizona Murder     8.1  413.
10 Arizona Assault  294    413.
# ... with 190 more rows
```

So we are using the `arrest` data frame. Now I would like fold "Total" into "Crime" so that "Total" is a value within Crime, just like "Murder."

I would also like to do the reverse. After "Total" is folded into "Crime", I want to use `pivot_wider` on "Crime" but only on values where `Crime == "Total"`.

Are these actions possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) janitor** Use `adorn_totals` from the janitor package ignoring the Total column. Note that within a `group_by` section that dot refers to the entire data set, not just that group, unless we refer to it within a `do` which is why we use `do`.

```
library(janitor)

res1 <- arrests %>%
  select(-Total) %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  do(adorn_totals(select(., -State), "row")) %>%
  ungroup
res1
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 250 x 3
   State   Crime    Value
   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Alabama Murder    13.2
 2 Alabama Assault  236  
 3 Alabama UrbanPop  58  
 4 Alabama Rape      21.2
 5 Alabama Total    328. 
 6 Alaska  Murder    10  
 7 Alaska  Assault  263  
 8 Alaska  UrbanPop  48  
 9 Alaska  Rape      44.5
10 Alaska  Total    366. 
# ... with 240 more rows
```

We can remove the Total rows and add a column

```
res1 %>% {
  left <- filter(., Crime != "Total")
  right <- filter(., Crime == "Total") %>% select(State, Total = Value)
  left_join(left, right, by = "State")
}
```

**2) reshape2** The reshape2 package is a forerunner of the pivot_* functions.  It does have margins functionality built in which seems not to have been continued in subsequent iterations in spread/gather and pivot_*.  This also works if we replace the `library` statement with `library(data.table)` .

```
library(reshape2)

res2 <- dcast(arrests, State + Crime ~ "Value", fun.aggregate = sum, 
  value.var = "Value", margins = "Crime")
res2
```

giving:

```
             State    Crime Value
1          Alabama  Assault 236.0
2          Alabama   Murder  13.2
3          Alabama     Rape  21.2
4          Alabama UrbanPop  58.0
5          Alabama    (all) 328.4
6           Alaska  Assault 263.0
7           Alaska   Murder  10.0
8           Alaska     Rape  44.5
9           Alaska UrbanPop  48.0
10          Alaska    (all) 365.5
...etc...
```

To create a Total column and remove the total rows, create a factor that identifies each row as a Value or Total row and then dcast the result to wide form filling in NAs with `na.locf`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)

fac <- factor(res$Crime == '(all)', labels = c("Value", "Total"))
dc <- dcast(res2, State + Crime ~ fac, value.var = "Value")
subset(na.locf(dc, fromLast = TRUE), Crime != '(all)')
```

or

```
left <- subset(res2, Crime != "(all)")
right <- subset(res2, Crime == "(all)", c(State, Value))
names(right) <- c("State", "Total")
merge(left, right, by = "State")
```

**3) sqldf** To use SQL add a level column which is 0 for detail records and 1 for Total records and then union the details and totals and sort.

```
library(sqldf)
res3 <- sqldf("select State, Crime, Value from (
  select 0 as level, State, Crime, Value from arrests
  union
  select 1 as level, State, 'Total' as Crime, sum(Value) as Total from arrests
  group by State)
  order by State, level")
```

To remove the total rows and insert a Total column

```
sqldf("select State, Crime, Value, Total
  from res3 a
  left join (
     select State, sum(Value) as Total 
       from res3 
       where Crime != 'Total' 
       group by State) using (State)
  where Crime != 'Total'")
```

**4) Base R**  This is straight forward in base R using `xtabs` and `addmargins`.

```
Total <- sum
tab <- addmargins(xtabs(Value ~ State + Crime, arrests), 2, FUN = Total)
DF <- as.data.frame(tab, responseName = "Value")
res3 <- DF[order(DF$State, DF$Crime == "Total"), ]
```

and modifying (2) we can use the following to remove the Total rows and add a Total column:

```
left <- subset(res3, Crime != "Total")
right <- subset(res3, Crime == "Total", c(State, Value))
names(right) <- c("State", "Total")
merge(left, right, by = "State")
```

Comment: Using `adorn_totals` with `do` was nice. Looks like there's no easy way to add the "Total" column though. It would be great if the `tidyverse` team added these functionalities. Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 5):

One option is `add_row`.  After doing a group split by 'State', loop over the `list` with `map` and add a row (`add_row` from `tibble`) with the first value of 'Total' column and remove the 'Total' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
arrests2 <- arrests %>%
         group_split(State) %>%
         map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
               add_row(State = .$State[1], Crime = 'Total',
                        Value = .$Total[1]) %>%
                select(-Total))
arrests2
# A tibble: 250 x 3
#  State   Crime    Value
# * <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 Alabama Murder    13.2
# 2 Alabama Assault  236  
# 3 Alabama UrbanPop  58  
# 4 Alabama Rape      21.2
# 5 Alabama Total    328. 
# 6 Alaska  Murder    10  
# 7 Alaska  Assault  263  
# 8 Alaska  UrbanPop  48  
# 9 Alaska  Rape      44.5
#10 Alaska  Total    366. 
# … with 240 more rows
```

Or another option is to `summarise` with the 'Total' value and then do a `bind_rows`

```
arrests %>% 
   group_by(State) %>% 
   summarise(Crime = 'Total', Value = first(Total)) %>% 
   bind_rows(arrests %>% select(-Total), .)  %>% 
   arrange(State)
```

---

Or using `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
arrests %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Value:Total) %>% 
    mutate(Crime = replace(Crime, name == 'Total', 'Total')) %>% 
    select(-name) %>%
    distinct()
# A tibble: 250 x 3
#   State   Crime    value
#   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 Alabama Murder    13.2
# 2 Alabama Total    328. 
# 3 Alabama Assault  236  
# 4 Alabama UrbanPop  58  
# 5 Alabama Rape      21.2
# 6 Alaska  Murder    10  
# 7 Alaska  Total    366. 
# 8 Alaska  Assault  263  
# 9 Alaska  UrbanPop  48  
#10 Alaska  Rape      44.5
# … with 240 more rows
```

---

If we need to do the reverse, then grouped by 'State', create the 'Total' column by extracting the 'Value' that corresponds to 'Crime' as 'Total', and `filter` out the row where the Crime is 'Total'

```
arrests2 %>%
    group_by(State) %>% 
    mutate(Total = Value[Crime == 'Total'])  %>%
    filter(Crime != 'Total')
# A tibble: 200 x 4
# Groups:   State [50]
#   State   Crime    Value Total
#   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Alabama Murder    13.2  328.
# 2 Alabama Assault  236    328.
# 3 Alabama UrbanPop  58    328.
# 4 Alabama Rape      21.2  328.
# 5 Alaska  Murder    10    366.
# 6 Alaska  Assault  263    366.
# 7 Alaska  UrbanPop  48    366.
# 8 Alaska  Rape      44.5  366.
# 9 Arizona Murder     8.1  413.
#10 Arizona Assault  294    413.
# … with 190 more rows
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite and pivot_wider only on Total? Or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @hmhensen i updated the post with the opposite option

Comment: Some would call you a hero. I would agree with them. I'm going to wait on the check mark. Maybe someone can come up with something more elegant on the `pivot_longer` version. Seems like a feature that should be included in `dplyr` already.

Comment: @hmhensen Not sure if pivoting is a good idea because we only need a single data point from Total for each 'State'

Comment: In this case it's only one value in Crime, but it could be more than one in other situations.

Comment: @hmhensen i meant frrom your `arrests` data, if the 'Total' values are differernt, which value sshould go into 'Total' row for each 'State'

Comment: Oh, right, only one value per state. I meant that it would be possible to want to take two or more variables gather them into "Crime", and then spread them back out.

Comment: @hmhensen i added an option with `pivot_longer`, then have to remove the duplicate with `distinct`, that would be a step I avoid

Comment: They're all pretty interesting. I'll see which work best for me. Thanks again!